# How to set all view with inside Relatvie layout in android

Tags: android

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/baseline_grid_7x"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/baseline_grid_7x"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_7x">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                app:adapter="@{imageSlideradapter}"
                app:currentItem="@{landingLoginViewModel.currentPage}"
                android:addOnPageChangeListener="@{landingLoginViewModel.pageChangeListener}"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/indicator"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/text_land_spacing"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/layout_padding_top"
                android:text="@string/label_businesscard_title"
                android:textColor="#3e4360"
                android:textSize="@dimen/businees_card_textmessage_size"
                android:textStyle="normal" />

            <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_top_15dp"
                app:centered="true"
                app:fillColor="#1ebad6"
                app:radius="@{landingLoginViewModel.pagerIndicatorCircle}"
                app:pageColor="#c6caca"

                app:snap="false" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/baseline_grid_2.5x"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/baseline_grid_2.5x"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_5x">


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_signin"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonbackroudnd"
                android:onClick="@{()->landingLoginViewModel.onSignIn()}"
                android:text="@string/label_sign_in"
                android:textColor="#ffffff" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn_signin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_3.5x"
                android:background="@drawable/roundbuttonborder"
                android:onClick="@{()->landingLoginViewModel.onSignUp()}"
                android:text="@string/label_sign_up"
                android:textColor="#00becc" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/oRtextLabel"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/btn_signup"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_5.5x"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/label_or"
                android:textColor="#8998a7"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"

                />


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linearlayout4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/oRtextLabel"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="@{()->landingLoginViewModel.onFacebook()}"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_5x">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/baseline_grid_3.5x"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/baseline_grid_3.5x"
                    android:src="@drawable/fb_icon" />

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/baseline_grid_1x"
                    android:text="@string/label_fcebook"
                    android:textColor="#465892"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/baseline_grid_2x"
                    android:textStyle="normal"

                    />

            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

This is my Xml i have divided full Screen in two part one for with each weight 1 and 1 for first Part every thing is comming correct but for second part i am trying to display lot of Control but last item goes to down while i want to fit all control please look my screen .look my current Screen last item goes down not visibile in small size Screen while in bigger its show ing please suggest me where am doing wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The RelativeLayouts inside the LinearLayout should have a height of 0dp if you are using weights.

Setting them to wrap_content doesn't garantee that the content will be out of bounds of the visible screen.

Comment: No working i have applied same still issue with less size screeen

Comment: You can't do magic. By applying the 0 height you have the two relative layouts using half and half of the screen.

Comment: how to apply Scrolling for whole layout i tired but view pager becomes hide @Juan

Comment: I don't have your assets, but copying the layout with the sugested change in hight, renders correctly. Perhaps look at the size of the buttons, or add your dimens file to the post.

Comment: can u check why ScollView is not working i have applied but its not working @Juan

Comment: I don't see any ScrollView in your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `RelativeLayout` height to 0dp and try.

Comment: Not working still same issue in lower Screen Size device

Comment: i did but not working also i tried to apply ScrollView but its not scrolling @Gau

Answer (score 0):

Use this xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="2"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/baseline_grid_7x"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/baseline_grid_7x"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_7x">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        app:adapter="@{imageSlideradapter}"
        app:currentItem="@{landingLoginViewModel.currentPage}"
        android:addOnPageChangeListener="@{landingLoginViewModel.pageChangeListener}"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/indicator"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/text_land_spacing"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/layout_padding_top"
        android:text="@string/label_businesscard_title"
        android:textColor="#3e4360"
        android:textSize="@dimen/businees_card_textmessage_size"
        android:textStyle="normal" />

    <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_top_15dp"
        app:centered="true"
        app:fillColor="#1ebad6"
        app:radius="@{landingLoginViewModel.pagerIndicatorCircle}"
        app:pageColor="#c6caca"

        app:snap="false" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/baseline_grid_2.5x"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/baseline_grid_2.5x"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_5x">


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_signin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonbackroudnd"
        android:onClick="@{()->landingLoginViewModel.onSignIn()}"
        android:text="@string/label_sign_in"
        android:textColor="#ffffff" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/btn_signup"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_signin"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_3.5x"
        android:background="@drawable/roundbuttonborder"
        android:onClick="@{()->landingLoginViewModel.onSignUp()}"
        android:text="@string/label_sign_up"
        android:textColor="#00becc" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/oRtextLabel"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn_signup"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_5.5x"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/label_or"
        android:textColor="#8998a7"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"

        />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/oRtextLabel"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="@{()->landingLoginViewModel.onFacebook()}"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/baseline_grid_5x">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/baseline_grid_3.5x"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/baseline_grid_3.5x"
            android:src="@drawable/fb_icon" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/baseline_grid_1x"
            android:text="@string/label_fcebook"
            android:textColor="#465892"
            android:textSize="@dimen/baseline_grid_2x"
            android:textStyle="normal"

            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try this if it works then its good if not then you may need scrollview to second half of your screen or may be on complete screen

Comment: And if it works for you then please dont forget to mark this post as answer.Happy Coding bro :)

Comment: i m not able to apply Scrollview in Full Screen  can u please  tell me how to apply